# FormFlow Accepting Default Value

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

Is there anyway, when being prompted for a value in a FormFlow dialog, of allowing the user to simply hit 'Enter' to accept the default value for a field?

For example I have a field defined as

```
    [Prompt("Appointments Starting At? {||}")]
    [Template(TemplateUsage.Unspecified, "today")]
    [Template(TemplateUsage.NoPreference, "today")]
    [Optional]
    public string StartDate;
```

When the user gets to this step they are prompted as expected

> Appointments Starting At? (current choice: today)

What I would like is for the user to simply hit 'Enter' to accept the default value. Is this possible, and if so how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think it's a good idea to use blank lines (pressing Enter) as a meaningful content in a conversation. Some messaging platforms (eg. Skype) may simply not send the empty lines along (if you just press Enter in the empty chat field nothing happens).

Maybe you can re-consider the logic and allow the user to alter the parameters upon confirmation? E.g. say "I am setting the appointment for today, please confirm or change the desired date".

Comment: You make a fair point. I hadn't considered the fact that the client might not send a blank entry through. Altering the logic is possible of course, but I was hoping not to put a confirmation step to makes things a bit simpler. Oh well, I guess a confirmation step will be needed.

Comment: @IanBoggs I agree with Dmitri . You should accept this as an answer :)